# Shrinking snowball paradox

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, mass, conservation-laws

This is a simplified problem posed to me for calculating the velocity after some fixed time.

I am just wondering if I am thinking about the paradox correctly here. Suppose that we have a snowball thrown (gravity neglected) with initial speed $v_0$ and mass $m_0$. The snowball is losing mass at a constant rate $k$ (this has to be the poor assumption...). Find the speed at a later time $t$. Clearly, we have
$$ \frac{dp}{dt} = 0 \implies p(t) = p_0 $$
for all $t$ where $p$ is the momentum. Solving for $v(t)$ we have
$$ v(t) = \frac{v_0}{1 - at}, \quad a = \frac{k}{m_0}. $$
This equation is fine for $at \ll 1$ but obviously something goes very wrong as $at \sim O(1)$. The snowball is approaching infinite speed. I can only assume that this is physically impossible so either the conservation of momentum is breaking down... or an assumption made was incorrect. The only assumptions I made was about an initial speed (hard to imagine this is a problem) or $dm/dt = -k$ is clearly incorrect.

In hindsight, this should have been obvious - the $dm/dt = -k$ should only be valid until $m = 0$, but this still seems to imply an absurd speed for the snowball. I'm left to imagine that these types of calculus problems are bad from a physical perspective in general. Perhaps I can save myself by having problems where $dm/dt = -km$ but this also leads to problems. Is there an lower limit on my snowball's mass??

Comment: You can't use conservation of momentum on a portion of the system.  It's invalid to assume that the portion of the snowball that remains gets to keep all the momentum.

Comment: I agree with @BowlOfRed:  If your lost mass has no momentum, then it's velocity would be zero.  So your snowball is effectively a rocket who's exhaust has a zero velocity in the original coordinate system.  Therefore, the faster the snowball gets, the more efficient the rocket gets because the delta V of the exhaust is always increasing.

Comment: Ok so what is needed to correctly find the speed - my intuition tells me that neglecting drag/gravity/etc., the speed of the snowball should remain constant. How to show this or is it just incorrect?

Comment: If there's no external forces (gravity, drag, etc.), then the center of mass of the snow/water/vapor will continue moving at the original velocity.  The velocity of the shrinking snowball will not change unless there is a bias in the speed or direction of the expanding water/vapor cloud.

Comment: Ah so as a weird hypothetical, if it was thrown in a "large" spaceship and slowly melting. The mixture of the snowball (now having an increasing proportion of water/vapor) will all be moving at the same speed. The "melted" parts will just be maintaining the same path. Am I thinking about that correctly?

Comment: @BowlOfRed but that's the only thing that makes the problem interesting, equation wise. Otherwise, it's just:  "there is a snowball: it melts".

Comment: @JEB That may be true.   But dp/dt = 0 isn't a valid starting point for a system with variable mass.

Comment: @Gregory You can compare to experience: If you throw a snowball (or a handfull of wet flour, or whatever) and it breaks apart in the air, then the pieces still continue roughly on the same trajectory, and will keep their velocity (ignoring air resistance). Eventually trajectories diverge because the remains have different ratios of inertia, weight and air resistance.

Comment: How exactly is the snowball losing mass? The answer to this affects the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$ \frac{dp}{dt} = 0 \implies p(t) = p_0 $$

This only applies to the combination of the remaining mass and lost mass, not just the remaining mass.

If the snowball is losing mass at a constant rate then it is losing momentum at a constant rate. But that lost momentum is strictly due to the loss of mass, not a reduction in velocity.

I'm going to assume there are no external forces acting on the snowball at any time (e.g., the loss of mass is due to radiant heating in the vacuum of outer space). Thus, if there is no external force at any time acting on either the remaining mass or lost mass, the velocity of both remaining mass and the lost mass will be constant and equal to the initial velocity of the snowball

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just making sure here, but is this very similar to my above thought experiment in the comments?

Comment: You mean the spaceship thing?

Comment: Correct. Your end conclusion is similar to mine, isn't it?

Comment: If I understand your example correctly, it appears so. The key is there can be no external force acting on the snowball affecting its momentum.